# How to indent paragraph in QtextEdit

Tags: qt, text

Everything works in another program, where only textedit, and in the main program - does not work. Apparently the reason is in some kind of Layout. Can you tell me what could be? I am attaching an excerpt from the code.))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QTextCursor, QTextBlockFormat
class TextEditor(QTextEdit):

 def __init__(self,parent):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):

    cursor = QTextCursor(self.document())
    cursor.select(QTextCursor.Document)
    fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
    fmt.setTextIndent(60)
    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
    font= QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.setFont(font)
          
    self.show()

 def insertFromMimeData(self, md):
  
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
        fmt.setTextIndent(cursor.blockFormat().textIndent())
        cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
        cursor.insertText(md.text())

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
 def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
    mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
    mainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
    self.textEdit = TextEditor(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.pig()
    self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)
    self.butclick()
    self.butclick2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [QTextBlockFormat.setTextIndent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextblockformat.html#setTextIndent) and [QTextCursor.mergeBlockFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextcursor.html#mergeBlockCharFormat) instead of [QTextEdit.setStyleSheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop):

```
    cursor = QTextCursor(self.textEdit.document())
    cursor.select(QTextCursor.Document)
    fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
    fmt.setTextIndent(60)
    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
```

Result:

[image: QTextEdit with indented text]

**UPD** As @ВалерияГригорьева rightfully pointed out, the indent is discarded when pasting plain text (although I would expect it should be taken from the current [block](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextblock.html) by the default implementation). Therefore we need to override [QTextEdit.insertFromMimeData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#drag-and-drop) and apply indentation on insert:

```
cursor = self.textCursor()
fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
fmt.setTextIndent(cursor.blockFormat().textIndent())
cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
cursor.insertText(md.text())
```

For pasting the rich text, on the other hand, we don't want to suppress indents because they are a part of the rich text formatting and thus we can rely on the default implementation of [QTextEdit.insertFromMimeData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData).

Complete code sample (for [PyQt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/)):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QTextCursor, QTextBlockFormat


class TextEditor(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # format text edit
        self.setPlainText(
                "Impedit voluptatem sequi quae quo quos. \n" + 
                "Asperiores non repellat culpa nihil. \n" + 
                "Voluptatum ut numquam dolorem molestiae voluptatem " + 
                "est modi necessitatibus. \n" + 
                "Hic rerum voluptas voluptatem. \n" + 
                "Ut expedita unde eum molestias voluptatem aut" + 
                "dignissimos dolor. \n" + 
                "Non illo dolore ut doloremque ut.")
        cursor = QTextCursor(self.document())
        cursor.select(QTextCursor.Document)
        fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
        fmt.setTextIndent(60)
        cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
        # setup UI
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Text indent')
        self.show()

    def insertFromMimeData(self, md):
        # leave processing of the rich text as it is
        if md.hasFormat("application/x-qrichtext") or md.hasHtml():
            super().insertFromMimeData(md)
        else:
            # force indentation from the current block 
            # (shouldn't Qt do this by default, huh?)
            cursor = self.textCursor()
            fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
            fmt.setTextIndent(cursor.blockFormat().textIndent())
            cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
            cursor.insertText(md.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TextEditor()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you show all code of your program, because i receive some errors with it

Comment: @ВалерияГригорьева updated with the complete code sample

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have a new problem :) This only works for manual text entry, and if I paste text into my widget, the formatting doesn't work again.

Comment: @ВалерияГригорьева see my update

Comment: If I delete the text and paste it, for example, from Word, then the formatting is broken again :(

Comment: @ВалерияГригорьева As I noted in the updated answer, this is expected because on pasting other rich text we try to preserve its formatting at the expense of the default formatting of the current document. If you wish to preserve the default formatting and sacrifice the source formatting, just remove the `if md.hasFormat...` part of the `insertFromMimeData` method and leave just the `else` part.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: @ВалерияГригорьева `insertFromMimeData` should be a method of a `QTextEdit` subclass. Replace `self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)` with `self.textEdit = TextEditor(self.centralwidget)` and insert the code of `TextEditor` from my answer.

Comment: self.textEdit = TextEditor(self.centralwidget)
TypeError: TextEditor.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @ВалерияГригорьева yes, the python interpretor is right, you should add a new parameter to `__init__` like `def __init__(self, parent):` and then pass this parameter to `super().__init__(parent)`

Comment: please, see my update:)

Comment: @ВалерияГригорьева, (a) please ask a separate question, and don't replace the current question with a new one exibiting a new problem - anyone not involved in the previous discussion may lose context; (b) add `pyqt` tag for PyQt-related questions; (c) don't use expressions like "it doesn't work", try to describe what you expect and what you observe instead; (d) don't abuse smileys :))), they express emotions and not meaning; (e) try not to address all questions to a single person essetially limiting the audience which can give you a solution, this is achieved by (a). I'm afk atm.